# How to change references in Doctrine ODM with mapped superclass?

Tags: php, doctrine-odm

I am using an abstract base class "BaseUser" and two classes "Admin" and "User". 
Now a user should become an admin.

Simply changing the discriminator field works, but there are a lot of references in other collections asuming  this document to be an "user". 
Thus there the "admin" is not found => NotFoundException

Is there a simple solution to **switch the class from user to admin** and **update all references?**

***BaseUser***

```
 /**
 * @ODM\Document
 * @ODM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_COLLECTION")
 * @ODM\DiscriminatorField("type")
 * @ODM\DiscriminatorMap({"admin"="Admin", "user"="User"})
 * @ODM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class BaseUser { ... }
```

***Admin***

```
/**
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class Admin extends BaseUser {...}
```

***User***

```
/**
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class User extends BaseUser {...}
```

***Example User Document:***

```
/* User */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123456789123456789"),
    "name" : "John",
    "type" : "user" //changed this to 'admin'
}
```

References in another document (for example BlogPost)

```
/** BlogPost */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc123456789"),       
    "headline" : "my first post",
    "text" : "lorem ipsum",
    "author" : {
        "$ref" : "BaseUser",
        "$id" : ObjectId("123456789123456789"),
        "type" : "user" //want this to be updated to 'admin' automatically
    }
}
```

**What did i try?**

Change the field "type" in the user document from value 'user' to 'admin'

=> Of course The reference "author" in BlogPost did not work anymore.

I could update all BlogPosts by hand, but this seems very error prone to me. Isn't there a better solution to transform this user?

(The code above is as simple as possible. In reality there are no such simple things as blog posts, but hundrets of different document classes referring to my user/admin class. So manually updating seems **really** hard)

Comment: Just curious, I would consider 'admin' as a 'role' the `user` has rather than a different type of user. i.e. it is the same user but has different privileges or duties to do? I would, perhaps, 'inject' them into the user as required? maybe? `$user->currentRole();` - `$user->setCurrentRole($role);`?

Comment: Yes "admin" is just a role. I think it was not a good idea to use inheritance for role management. What do you mean by inject into user class? All admin should become users with enhanced role management? (i.e. `$user->can('seeAdminInterface')` )

Comment: Your approach with `'can'` is very useful. Depends how you want to actually implement it ar run time. imo,  there is no 'one true way' :)

Comment: yes this could work. Keep the discriminatormap but remove all entries (like admin) and use 'user' as default discriminator value.